# What my causes junk keyboard input in Android Studio, after running Flutter project

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I'm trying to run the Flutter examples provided with flutter in Android Studio (linux).
I seem to be getting junk when I type text into the keyboard (at least in the ('Pixel 2 API 29' emulator).
I don't think there's anything wrong with my settings (attached, below).

The is what I get if I type 'abcdef' from the host's keyboard. Any idea how to fix?

Other symptoms:

- The problem appears after running some Flutter project (e.g. ones from the Flutter sample library -- not very interesting). It doesn't seem to matter which project.
- *After* running (and debugging) a Flutter app, the keyboard input permanently borked both for the app I am debugging, and also within Android in general, until the VM is rebooted.

[image]
[image]

UPDATE: Output of the Event Log window:

> 9/14/19 7:42 PM   Emulator:
>   statvfs('/home/me/.android/avd/Pixel_2_API_29.avd/snapshots/default_boot/ram.img')
>   failed: No such file or directory
>
> 7:42 PM   Emulator: Xlib:  extension "NV-GLX" missing on display ":0".
>
> 8:42 PM   Emulator: Trying to erase a non-existent color buffer with
>   handle 0
>
> 8:52 PM   Emulator: Trying to erase a non-existent color buffer with
>   handle 0
>
> 9/16/19 10:24 AM  Emulator: Trying to erase a non-existent color buffer
>   with handle 0
>
> 10:26 AM  Emulator: Trying to erase a non-existent color buffer with
>   handle 0
>
> 10:28 AM  Emulator: Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: have you tried testing on another emulator or directly on a device ?

Comment: Yes -- other emulators work fine. I'm just trying to find out what's up with this emulator.

Comment: Although -- after deleting and creating an emulator from a new image, the problem come back *after* running a Flutter project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw it today too. I have not points to answer you, but i found the solution: Open your Android Studio and update the emulator (mine ask to update)